# Need an easy example of actionscript 3 and facebook API integration

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, facebook

im programmer in PHP, AS2, AS3 and others, i want to develop a flash application for facebook, i know a litle bit about how to start with the API configuration and that kind of thinks, i know how to integrate PHP scripts with flash (but in AS2).

So, i cant find a good (and simple) example of an app made in flash (AS3) who integrates with the facebook api and do some simple stuff like return the pictures of yours friends...

Well, i think you guys can help me with this, thanks! and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look also in "Tour de Flex" (aplication tutorial for Flash/Flex/AIR) that has running code demostration of FaceBook API from Flash...

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Adobe solution for communication with Facebook, here is the main page: [Adobe Flash and Facebook](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've written a tutorial on how to achieve connection with Facebook from within Flash using just native ActionScript3 and the Facebook PHP SDK:

http://icodethings.tumblr.com/post/17597008914/connect-with-facebook-workflow-from-flash-as3-using